# Avoid duplicate files in different android drawable folders

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, drawable, resolution

I'm developing an android game and will try cover as many different phone and tabled screen sizes and resolutions as possible. To make it easier to handle graphics I've designed some of my icons so that for example a 7" mdpi tablet uses same icons as an xhdpi phone.

That means I have put exactly the same icon file in drawable-xhdpi folder as in drawable-sw600dp-mdpi. I also have same files in drawable-land-xhdpi as in drawable-sw600dp-land-mdpi. It doesn't feel good to have duplicate files, can it be avoided somehow? Or how smart is eclipse compiler, can it detect duplicate files and compress the apk file accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid duplicating image files by using aliases. An image alias is an XML resource file containing a `<bitmap />` tag. Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#XmlBitmap) for the syntax.

In your case I think you should name your resources differently for phone and tablets if they don't end up having the same density-independent size. From what I understand, your tablet images are bigger than your phone images, which is generally not a good idea.

Comment: The xml bitmap sounds good but what I understand I cannot put the xml file in drawable-sw600dp-mdpi and force a link to a source file in drawable-xhdpi (without renaming the source different from the xml)? I also think I should name resources differently and link correctly from different layout files but then I definitely will have duplicates. And yes, icons are larger on tablets in my case because the design will not look good otherwise.

Comment: After some more thinking, I guess I could put all source files in drawables main folder, rename them like ic_mdpi, ic_hdpi, ic_xhdpi, etc. and then use bitmap xml to link. Not very android stylish though..

Comment: Yes, you could name the images with their size and only reference aliases from your app, but this is kind of messy because it sorts of defeats the purpose of automatic image file selection according to density.